# C# error: the name 'handled' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, class, events

In the code below on Visual Studio express C# i get an error saying that the name 'handled' does not exist in the current context. What am I doing wrong? return handled informs the software that it should not continue doing what it would normally do on a double click.

```
public class SettingsComponentAttributes : ComponentAttributes
{
    public override ObjectResponse RespondToMouseDoubleClick(Canvas sender, CanvasMouseEvent e)
    {
        ((SettingsComponent)Owner).ShowSettingsGui();
        return handled;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean e.Handled?  Where is `handled` coming from?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair, handled is one of the possible values that the ObjectResponse function should be returning. return handled informs the software that it should not continue doing what it would normally do on a double click. my problem is thet when typing return on VS it doesn't automatically suggest handled.

Comment: Sorry I got it, I added return return ObjectResponse.Handled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is how I solved the issue:

```
public class SettingsComponentAttributes : ComponentAttributes
{
    public override ObjectResponse RespondToMouseDoubleClick(Canvas sender, CanvasMouseEvent e)
    {
        ((SettingsComponent)Owner).ShowSettingsGui();
        return ObjectResponse.handled;
    }
}
```